# How to display data on Xamarin.Android edit text using Web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I'm trying to display the data from SQL server using web API, get method on edit text in Xamarin.Android. The data will display on the edit text once the button is clicked. I've followed all the steps (exactly) as in the YouTube tutorial but unfortunately, the data did not show up on the edit text, instead it shows JSON format on the screen. What should I do to fix this problem?

I've tried using Web services, still didn't show up.

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PersonalInfo);

    ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    EditText email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
    EditText firstName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
    EditText lastName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtLastName);
    EditText gen = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtGender);
    EditText ic = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtIC);
    EditText address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAddress);
    EditText phoneNo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
    EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
    EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPwd);
    EditText payment = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPayMethod);
    Button btnGetAcc = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGetAcc);

    btnGetAcc.Click += async delegate
    {
        VehicleRecord vehicRec = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "http://192.168.0.135/PMSAPI/api/clients/" + username.Text.ToString();
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        try
            {
                vehicRec = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleRecord>(json);
                if (vehicRec == null)
                {
                    //check for an array just in case
                    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleRecord[]>(json);
                    if (items != null && items.Length > 0)
                    {
                        vehicRec = items[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
    };
}
```

The expected output should display data from SQL server on edit text but the actual output is it display all the data in JSON-format.

The actual output:
[image: The actual output]

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is to show the JSON if `vehicRec == null`.

The JSON shown in the image is that of an array. Notice the `[]` square brackets wrapping the JSON object.

```
[{....}]
```

This would mean that asking to deserialize to an object would fail. Refactor the code to desrialize to an array and then extract the desired object out of the result.

```cs
//...omitted for brevity

var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

try {
    vehicRec = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleRecord>(json);
    if(vehicRec == null) {
        //check for an array just in case
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleRecord[]>(json);
        if(items != null && items.Length > 0) {
            vehicRec = items[0];
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { }

if (vehicRec == null)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, json, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else
{
    firstName.Text = vehicRec.firstName;
    lastName.Text = vehicRec.lastName;
    gen.Text = vehicRec.gender;
    ic.Text = vehicRec.icNo;
    address.Text = vehicRec.address;
    phoneNo.Text = vehicRec.phoneNo;
    username.Text = vehicRec.username;
    password.Text = vehicRec.password;
    payment.Text = vehicRec.paymentMethod;
}

//...omitted for brevity
```

Note also in the JSON that there are multiple items in the array. I would suggest you consider using a list to display the records in the array.

The code above will only show the first item in the array but can be easily refactored to use the array as a data source for a list view.

It was also noted that the names of the fields in the JSON do not match that of the class being populated. Which will cause the properties to not get any values.

From one of your previous questions I was able to see that you defined the class as

```
public class VehicleRecord {
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string icNo { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phoneNo { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string plateNo { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string col { get; set; }
    public string paymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

But the JSON shown in the image has all fields prefixed with a `cl`.

You would need to add a mapping so the JsonConverter knows how to populate the class

```
public class VehicleRecord {
    [JsonProperty("clFirstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("clLastName")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("clGender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }


    //...etc
}
```

You may be better off using a JSON parser to generate the class for you which would also include the attributes to map the properties.

Comment: i can't use listview because the user will input the username on the edittext and click the "Get acc" button to display all the information according to the specific username on edit text. But when i tried the above code, there's nothing happen. Can you show me how the details will appear on edit text based on specific username? @Nkosi

Comment: i have to use edit text because later the user have to make an update on details.

Comment: the edit text should display details according to the username input.  Not all records from json. Help me pls!!! :@Nkosi

Comment: @Yonce As I already stated, the code above will work on one record even if there are multiple in the JSON. I was simply pointing out that the data shown in your image had more than one item in it.

Comment: but how do u bind it with the edit text? idk why but the api only show one record.

Comment: sorry. ok i did replaced the code already. But how do you bind it with edit text? When i run the code, still the edit text didn't show any record details. @Nkosi

Comment: that is one way to do it but the `paymentMethod` is more readable than `clPaymentMethod`. So look at my suggestion on what to do.

Comment: i tried to make a class as what u asked but idk when i right the JSON property line, there's an error on Name="clFirstName". Sorry, i'm a bit blur coding for android app because im new in this application coding. @Nkosi

Comment: Actually _cl_ is based on my attribute in database.

Comment: i've tried all the codes as you told. still nothing appears on edit text once the button is clicked @Nkosi

Comment: im having an error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` @Nkosi

Comment: I gave up doing this. Everything seems not functioning :(

Comment: my app cannot display the first ever output. It keeps saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Help me pls @Nkosi

Comment: @Yonce I am trying my best to assist you. Based on what you have provided the above should work. But you seem to be having issues with some of the basics. I suggest breaking this up into smaller manageable parts.